# simple average calculation in Access XP report

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, average

i have a database used at work for evaluating calls, the database is somewhat dated and originally created on Access XP. Once evaluated these calls are given a score out of 5 which is entered along with other data (such as date, employee name, etc) on a form. I have the reports set up so they generate when you enter the employee name and then the start of a date period and the end of a date period, the report will then generate and show the entries made between those 2 dates. i am trying to include a section on the report which shows an average of the call score for the employee for the period chosen. I understand this may be pretty simple but i'm struggling! cheers, Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work out group calculations on reports, you can either put them in the group header/footer, or report header/footer (for calculations over the whole report).

In this case, placing a textbox with something like `=AVG([CallScore])` as the control source in the Report Footer should work.

This page should explain more about using aggregate functions in reports: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/summing-in-reports-HA001122444.aspx